# Константы Intent системных событий

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver

Почти любое системное событие можно обработать с помощью `BroadcastReceiver`.
Например, если я хочу, чтобы запускался какой-либо сервис после запуска телефона, я создам `BroadcastReceiver` с фильтром **ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED**

Вопрос: есть ли где список этих констант, где каждая будет подписана, при каком событии она срабатывает на русском?

Comment: Фразой "на русском" вы значительно усложнили задачу. Вам действительно это важно?

Comment: Если вы и дальше собираетесь программировать, то лучше всего прямо сейчас браться за английский. На русском нет и десятой части документации и всего прочего, что может понадобиться. А пока онлайн-переводчики в помощь что ли ..

Comment: тогда можно обойтись и описанием в классе Intent)

Comment: Как бы [в API класса Intent](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Intent.html#constants) они все и описаны